# Close div when clicking Background div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to close a Div when i click on the Background div(SearchBlur).
My problem is if i click on the shown div it closes also.

here is my javascrip code

```
SearchBlur.addEventListener('click', closePopup);

function closePopup(){

   if(counter == 1){
        $( "#search_input" ).animate({ "left": "-=300px"}, "normal" );
        $('.SearchBlur').fadeOut("normal");
        counter = 0;
    }

}
```

here my html

```
<div class="SearchBlur" id="SB_Back">
    <div class="div_container" id="container">
        <div class="grid_div">
            <div id="gridwrapper">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the Programm looks like this [image]

i want to close the popup wehn i click on the dark background

sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: can you show us css

Comment: `if i click on the shown div` what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`event.stopPropagation();`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)  `onclick` the child you want

```js
var counter = 1;
$( ".SearchBlur" ).on( "click", function() {
 if(counter == 1){
        $( "#search_input" ).animate({ "left": "-300px"}, "normal" );
        $('.SearchBlur').fadeOut("normal");
        counter = 0;
    }
});
$( ".div_container" ).on( "click", function() {
 event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.SearchBlur{
background:blue;
}
.div_container{
width:100px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="SearchBlur" id="SB_Back">
    <div class="div_container" id="container">
        <div class="grid_div">
                <div id="gridwrapper">div_container
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try add a listener to the child div with following code

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

Which div are you trying to close?

From what I can see, you're fading out the highest level div, so all markup nested within SearchBlur will also be hidden. I assume you want to target a deeper nested div, for example:

```js
function closePopup(){
   if(counter == 1){
        $( "#search_input" ).animate({ "left": "-=300px"}, "normal" );
        $('.div_container').fadeOut("normal");
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to close all but oly when i click on the SearchBlur and not on the div container. but wehn i click on the container it closes also.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way your html looks like:

```
<div class="blur">
    <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
```

Your JS is just like this:

```
$('.blur').on('click', function (e){
  if (e.target === this)
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Here is codepen: https://codepen.io/alexmoronto/pen/xaKvxg